# Построить график c#

Tags: c#, winforms, график

Добрый день, подскажите пожалуйста, как построить график многочлена :
сам многочлен p(x)=An*X^n + An-1*X^n-1+...+A1X+A0

```
 int[] array= new int[10];
int i, num, power;
float x;

num=4;
x=1;

array[0] = 3;
array[1] = -5;
array[2] = 6;
array[3] = 8;
array[4] = -9;

power = num;

double k = 0;

for (i = 0; i <= num; i++)
{
    k += Math.Pow(x, power--) * array[i];
 //   richTextBox1.AppendText(Convert.ToString(k) +"\n");

}
```

как щас построить график ?

Comment: сам многочлен :p(x)=An*X^n + An-1*X^n-1+...+A1X+A0

Comment: и да, желательно график в picturebox нарисовать, тобишь без сторонних компонентов.. можете помочь ?

Comment: А что такое `PictureBox`? У вас WinForms, что ли?

Comment: @VladD скорее всего WinForms, и похоже что задание таки учебное. Не уверен насчет дубля, там был вопрос что именно выбрать при наличии знаний как построить, тут похоже наоборот

Comment: @rdorn: Если WinForms, то не дубль, т. к. тот ответ про WPF.

Comment: да, WinForms. Да, я прост не знаю как построить график, когда уже вычислил многочлен. По идее, в теории, нужно рисовать точки, а потом их соединить, но на практике чет не очень...

Comment: вы мне поможите ?

Comment: помогу, только есть еще пара вопросов. У вас уже готова функция, которая будет возвращать значение y по заданному x? Можете получить массив x-ов и соответствующих им y-ов? Без этого придется писать демонстрационный вариант на библиотечной функции

Comment: можете немного пояснить ? мне дан многочлен по которому я должен построить график, вычисление многочлена я привел выше, так вот, мне брать за точку An*X^n , потом An-1*X^n-1 и тп или конечный ответ ? и еще, как мне получить значения y (я подразумевал , что я раньше вычислил x) ? что-то я сильно туплю, извините

Comment: дополнил ответ, надеюсь изменить под ваше конкретное задание сами сумеете...

Comment: спасибо, попробую

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Для начала вам будет достаточно стандартного класса **[Chart](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.chart(v=vs.110).aspx)**, хотя есть и сторонние компоненты для построения красивых графиков, но мне кажется, что сначала лучше разобраться со стандартным контролом. В документации на MSDN есть довольно подробный **[Tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd489237.aspx)**. Основные моменты покажу в коде, подробности в официальной документации.

```
class ChartForm : Form
{
    public ChartForm()
    {
        //создаем элемент Chart
        Chart myChart = new Chart();
        //кладем его на форму и растягиваем на все окно.
        myChart.Parent = this;
        myChart.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        //добавляем в Chart область для рисования графиков, их может быть
        //много, поэтому даем ей имя.
        myChart.ChartAreas.Add(new ChartArea("Math functions"));
        //Создаем и настраиваем набор точек для рисования графика, в том
        //не забыв указать имя области на которой хотим отобразить этот
        //набор точек.
        Series mySeriesOfPoint = new Series("Sinus");
        mySeriesOfPoint.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
        mySeriesOfPoint.ChartArea = "Math functions";
        for (double x = -Math.PI; x <= Math.PI; x += Math.PI / 10.0) 
        {
            mySeriesOfPoint.Points.AddXY(x, Math.Sin(x));
        }
        //Добавляем созданный набор точек в Chart
        myChart.Series.Add(mySeriesOfPoint);
    }
}
```

Вот собственно минимум кода для рисования графика на форме. Здесь не приведены ни настройки осей координат и сетки, ни другие графические рюшечки которые поддерживает данный контрол, т.к. примеры применения практически всех возможностей этого контрола есть в официальной документации, ссылка выше.

Дополнение:

Вам нужно вычисление многочлена вынести в отдельную функцию. Это можно сделать например так

```
double Polynom(double x, double[] coefficients)
{
    double y = 0.0;
    double currentX = 1.0;
    for(int i = 0; i<coefficients.Length; i++)
    {
        y += currentx * coefficients[i];
        currentx *= x;
    }
    return y;
}
```

И подставить ее вместо `Math.Sin` в моем примере.