# Построение графика произвольной функции c#

Tags: c#, winforms, поиск-библиотек

подскажите библиотеку для построения произвольных графиков функции в C#. т.е передаёшь например f(x)=sin(x) и на какой-нибудь канвас выводит синусоиду.

Comment: В каком виде у вас передаётся функция? Символическом или как `Func<double, double>`?

Comment: [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/534365/198316) уже смотрели?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Зачем искать какие-то библиотеки, если это легко можно реализовать с помощью стандартных средств WinForms: для построения графиков использовать Chart, а для вычисления выражений - скажем, JavaScript в невидимом WebBrowser. Конечно, можно задействовать средства динамической компиляции и вычислять выражения на C#, но, я думаю, с JavaScript попроще будет.

Данный пример позволяет построить график функции, задаваемой любым JS-выражением:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting;

namespace WinFormsTest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        protected WebBrowser wb;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            //инициализируем WebBrowser для вычислений
            wb = new WebBrowser();
            wb.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;//убрать на этапе отладки, чтобы видеть ошибки

            //подготавливаем JS-код для вычисления произвольного выражения
            string js = @"function execute(script){return eval(script);}";

            wb.DocumentText =
                "<html><head><script type=\"text/javascript\">"+
                js+"</script></head><body>Hello World</body></html>";
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Построение графика функции
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="ch">Элемент управления Chart</param>
        /// <param name="expression">Математическое выражение функции от аргумента x в JavaScript-синтаксисе</param>
        /// <param name="x_min">Начало интервала значений аргумента</param>
        /// <param name="x_max">Конец интервала значений аргумента</param>
        /// <param name="dx">Шаг изменения аргумента</param>
        public void PlotGraph(Chart ch,string expression, double x_min, double x_max,double dx)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("x", typeof(Double));
            dt.Columns.Add("y", typeof(Double));

            DataRow row;
            double x;
            string s;
            object y;

            //создаем культуру, совместимую с представлением чисел в JS
            CultureInfo culture =
                new CultureInfo( CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name);
            culture.NumberFormat.NegativeSign = "-";
            culture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";
            
            //создаем таблицу значений
            for (x = x_min; x < x_max; x += dx)
            {
                row = dt.NewRow();
                row["x"] = x;

                //подготавливаем выражение для JS
                s = "var x=" + x.ToString(culture) + "; " + expression + ";";
                
                //вычисляем выражение
                y = wb.Document.InvokeScript("execute",new object[] { s });

                //преобразуем результат из строки в Double
                row["y"] = Convert.ToDouble(y, culture);
                dt.Rows.Add(row);
            }

            //добавляем ряд в Chart
            ch.DataSource = dt;
            Series ser = new Series();
            ser.Name = expression;
            ser.XValueMember = "x";
            ser.YValueMembers = "y";
            ser.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
            ch.Series.Clear();
            ch.Series.Add(ser);
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //пример использования
            PlotGraph(chart1, "Math.sin(x)+0.3*Math.sin(15*x)", 0.0, Math.PI * 2, 0.1);
            
        }
    }
}
```

Если перенастроить WebBrowser на новую версию IE через реестр, можно и прямо в нем графики строить, через HTML5 Canvas.

Comment: JavaScript в невидимом WebBrowser? Вы уверены, что это хороший совет? Вы представляете себе скорость?

Comment: @VladD У меня построение графика приведенным кодом занимает 11 мс (из них 7 мс - непосредственно вычисления на JS). Последующие вызовы (после прогрева) - еще меньше. Инициализация WebBrowser занимает чуть больше - 47 мс, но ее достаточно сделать один раз, используя один экземпляр класса во всех формах.

Comment: От 0 до 6.28 с шагом 0.1? То есть 62 итерации? Это ужасно медленно.

Comment: @VladD Есть способы сделать это быстрее, но они либо небезопасны, либо требуют подключения дополнительных библиотек, поэтому я не вижу смысла их тут приводить. Скорость достаточна, чтобы не вызывать видимой задержки в UI.

Comment: Ну например вот такой способ: https://pastebin.com/SmCuqr6K стартует за 77 миллисекунд, и вычисляет 62 миллиона значений за 5 с половиной секунд. Без дополнительных библиотек, и настолько же безопасен, как и ваш.

Comment: @VladD Но для построения графика функции не нужны миллионы значений. При любом практическом сценарии никакого выигрыша нет, из-за накладных расходов на компиляцию. В текущем виде, этот код производит динамическую сборку, которую никак нельзя выгрузить из памяти, когда она становится не нужна. Более того, если подать на вход что-то вроде "(double)(System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(\"Program.exe\").Id)", можно выполнить любую программу на компьютере пользователя.

Comment: Ну, эээ, вариант с eval'ом в парсере может от вашего имени запостить что-нибудь в Фейсбук. Так что с безопасностью одинаково плохо.

Answer (score 2):

Все-таки здесь два этапа:

1. Рассчитать координаты точек на графике. Для этого есть mXparser http://mathparser.org/
2. Построить сам график из этих точек. Здесь миллион вариантов, выбирайте на вкус https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=Tags%3A%22plotting%22

Answer (score 1):

Хоть это и **не точный ответ** на вопрос по поводу библиотек, т.к. сам тоже не нашел. 
Есть один запасной для вас вариант: 
Создаете функцию которая принимает `x` и строку фукнции, вида `"x^2+2*x-3"` 
В строке, символ 'x' заменяете на значение переменной `x`
что бы вышло что то типа:

```
x = 3
"3^2+2*3-3"
```

Алгоритмом польской нотации считаете выражение, и возвращаете ответ.
Примеры и объяснения польской записи хорошо доступны. 
Создаете массив для отображения графика. И в своем массиве для каждого элемента вызываете функцию, передавая x на промежутке (xmin;xmax), и сам вид функции как string.

Для самих графиков можно использовать Chart в .NET