# График C# с использованием базы данных MSSQL

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, sql-server

Как нарисовать график прямой, по нажатию кнопки на форме (WinForm), с использованием данных из БД, которая находится в MSSQL? Пример таблицы на скриншоте снизу.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вопрос основной какой - как построить график или как получить данные с БД?

Comment: @pavl_o Вопрос один, как построить график, на основе данных из БД, я вроде так и написал в вопросе.

Comment: Не так понял значит вопрос сразу) Думаю ответ на ваш вопрос находится [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/534293/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA-c)

Comment: @pavl_o Жалко, что плохо разбираюсь в коде... и то, как из бд загрузить туда данные...

Comment: Получается у вас все-таки 2 вопроса как я и писал ранее. Во вопросу как построить график я вам дал ссылку на вопрос, где есть подробный ответ. А по вопросу как получить данные из БД, тут уже много нюансов. Поищите в интернете статьи, например с поисковым запросом `c# работа с mssql`

Comment: @pavl_o вопрос 1, как по вот этим данные, которые находятся в таблице, сделать график и все, никаких данных получать или еще что то не надо мне.  Окей, скажу по другому, это координаты точек x = 15.25 y 11.3  и тд , получается что точки идут по возрастающей и если их соединить получиться прямая линия, что мне и нужно

Comment: Ну сделайте для теста просто массив значений, и скопируйте код, добавьте к себе и измените часть где идет вычисление в цикле замените на свои значения из массива. Поиграйтесь с кодом, почитайте документацию

Comment: Разделите ваш вопрос на два: 1) как получить данные из БД, 2) как построить график. И задайте их отдельно (можете отредактировать этот вопрос и создать второй).

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Даже если разделю, я все равно очень плохо разбираюсь в программировании и пока сложно все это понять ...

Comment: Тогда наймите программиста за деньги. Вам на биржу фриланса.